# Catch unhandled exceptions from any thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, unhandled-exception

### Edit

The answers to this question where helpful thanks I appreciate the help :) but I ended up using: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Handling-Unhandled-47492d0b#content

---

### Original question:

I want to show a error message when my application crashes.

Currently I have:

`App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication5.App"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException"  // <----------------
      StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>             
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Code-behind of `App.xaml`:

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{        
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Unhandled Exception!");
        }
    }
}
```

That solution works great when the error occurs on the main thread. Now my problem is how will I be able to catch errors that happen on a different thread also?

In other words: when I press this button I am able to catch the exception: (`App_DispatcherUnhandledException` gets called!)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        int.Parse("lkjdsf");
    }
```

But I am not able to catch this exception:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int.Parse("lkjdsf");
        });
    }
```

How will I be able to catch all exceptions regardless if they happen on the main thread or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to handle uncaught exception.

Comment: `System.AppDomain.UnhandledException` gives me an error weird why? I will keep trying.

Comment: got it to work I had to do:  `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);`

Comment: @TonoNam Does your app gets closed after you catch `System.AppDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: Nope application still runs. I was just wanted to know whenever exceptions occurred on different threads.

Comment: This does not capture unhandled exceptions from other threads.

`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => throw new Exception("Hey this is an exception"));`

Would not be captured by this event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Use AppDomain.UnhandledException event to catch this exception. than you need to use the dispatcher to be able to show this exception in a messageBox (this is because only ui thread can show messages)